# Did Sai baba of Shirdi mention anywhere that he will born again?

Tags: sai

During his lifetime, do [Shirdi Sai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sai_Baba_of_Shirdi) mention that he will born again?

Comment: See related meta post [Are questions about Shirdi Sai Baba and his teachings on-topic?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1609)

Comment: Questions on Shiridi Sai are ON topic. He has a large following among Hindus.

Comment: @LazyLubber you can discuss/post an answer on meta.